# Display 13 months of data using SQL Pivot query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

[This is how my data is stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhPuV.png)

I am trying to write a pivot to get the below results

[This is how I want to display it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LoPW.png)

The stored data will always append data each month. The data that I have to display should only display 13 months of data. I have tried to write different querys one of the examples is below. I was really hoping that this would work  but I got stuck with the querying 13 months of data.

```
DECLARE @date AS datetime
set  @date = (
    select ReportMonth 
    from InvTypeReptBrkDown_DND 
    WHERE reportmonth  between DATEADD(Year, -1, getdate()) AND getdate())


SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ReportMonth,
        category,
        ctpertype,
        CtperType_Freight
    FROM InvTypeReptBrkDown_DND
 ) AS P

 -- For Sales
PIVOT
(
    count([CtperType]) FOR reportmonth IN (@date)
) AS pv1
```

Can anyone please assist me with this query.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: hello the data is stored in SQL and I am trying to build the display in SSRS.

Comment: You mean MS SQL Server? Add <sql-server> tag if that's the case. (The <sql> tag is for the ANSI SQL standard, not the Microsoft product. But you can still keep that tag as well.)

Comment: oh thank you so much.

Comment: The PIVOT functionality is SQL Server exclusive.